# Nondimensionalizing a mixed predator-prey system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis

I want to Nondimensionalize the following system
$$V'=rV(1-V/K)-aVP,$$ $$P'=-sP+abVP.$$ Which is a predator-prey system where we consider a logistic growth for the prey instead of a malthusian one. I know how to proceed when both are logistic or both are like the Lotka-Volterra ones, but in the mixed case none of the variable changes seems to work. Any help will be very appreciated. My advances so far:
Take $x=V/V^*$, $y=P/P^*$ and $\tau=\alpha t$ for some constants $V^*, P^*,\alpha$ to determinate. Then we have $$\frac{dx}{d\tau}=\frac{r}{\alpha}x-\frac{r}{\alpha K}V^*x^2-aP^*xy,$$ $$\frac{dy}{d\tau}=\frac{-s}{\alpha}y+\frac{abV^*}{\alpha}xy.$$ Taking $\alpha=r$, $\beta=s/r$, $P^*=r/a$ and $V^*=r/(ab)$ i end up with $$x'=x-\frac{r}{abK}x^2-xy,$$ $$y'=-\beta y+xy.$$ I dont know how to conclude it

Comment: You can change 3 variables, $P,V$ and time $T$, you have 5 parameters. It is quite natural when in the reduced form one or two parameters remain non-normalized, free to change. Can you show your most advanced effort?

Comment: Already edited it!

Comment: So you end up with 2 remaining parameters. As said, this does not get better. I would have made the first equation parameter free, starting with $V^*=K$ and $\alpha=r$, but that is a question of taste if no further context is given. Then the second equation has the two remaining parameters.